# How to add a package from command line in flutter?

Tags: flutter, command-line, terminal, package

`npm` (and so `yarn`) has a great feature that you can add needed packages just by knowing the package name (like `yarn add xxx_yyy`) and it adds the latest stable release to your project. Does flutter have any equivalent hero? Or we have to search our needed package on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) and find version to add to our `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: No Flutter doesn't support npm or yarn command Flutter only allows to add the package by adding into ```pubspec.yaml```

Comment: @axelblaze, I myself have already know it does not support `npm` or `yarn`, I'm asking about a same **THING**.

Comment: I don't think any such tool exist yet, but I think it is possible to create one though.

Comment: @10101010 Agree. But I don't really have any problem with current situation to be honest.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

- Add a package as a **direct dependency:**

  ```
  flutter pub add <package-name>
  ```
- Add a package as a **`dev-dependency`:**

  ```
  flutter pub add -d <package-name>
  ```
- **Remove a package:**

  ```
  flutter pub remove <package-name>
  ```

Note: You can also use **`dart`** command instead of **`flutter`** above.

Comment: How to add packege to dev_dependencies from command line?

Comment: @e79ene Use `d` for example: `dart|flutter pub add -d xxx`

Answer (score 7):

You can manage packages with `flutter pub` command.

`flutter pub add` - adds packages to your project's `pubspec.yaml` and downloads them. So you don't have to run `flutter pub get`.

```
flutter pub add <package>
```

Add a package to your project's dependencies.

```
flutter pub add --dev <package>
```

Similarly adds package to `dev_dependencies`.

```
flutter pub remove <package>
```

Removes the package from your project's dependencies.

Documentation: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd

Note: (`flutter pub` is the same as `dart pub`)

Comment: How can we add multiple packages with `flutter pub add` ?

Answer (score 5):

## Update 2

Based on @CopsOnRoad [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67138074/1589683), now dart has `add` command which is the best way for adding packages from cmd. [Full documentation is here](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-add).

#### Update

Right now you can have exactly similar experience like npm or yarn in flutter with the help of [get_cli](https://pub.dev/packages/get_cli) package. One of the tools it provides will let you just write the package name and it automatically installs the latest version with mentioning the version number inside the yaml file.

*From its documentation*

```
// To install a package in your project (dependencies):
get install camera

// To install several packages from your project:
get install http path camera 

// To install a package with specific version:
get install path:1.6.4

// You can also specify several packages with version numbers

// To install a dev package in your project (dependencies_dev): 
get install flutter_launcher_icons --dev
```

#### Old answer

About the cli verb `add`, there is no any equivalent in flutter and pub yet. But about the versioning and adding packages just with their names, try to add them in `pubspec.yaml` file without version number. Just like this:

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  mobx:
  flutter_mobx:
  dio: ^2.1.13
```

Comment: Thanks! I wish flutter would add the version (after fetching the package for the first time), so it doesn't fetch it again (to get the newer version).

Comment: @AlirezaXX `pubspec.lock` file will do. due to the [dart documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/packages) you have to add it to source control (just for non-shared applications)